# Blank configuration page

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, web-applications, phpfox

I want to install `phpfox`, but after two steps, I see a blank page and not configuration page.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually due to an error which is being hidden. A few things to check...
Most of this is defined in your php.ini file which you can modify to change it globally. You will have to restart apache.

1. Check your `error_log` file

   - On the index.php add `ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/log');` to specify log file
2. Turn on displaying of errors `display_errors`

   - On the index.php add `ini_set('display_errors', true);`
3. Echo your way placing `echo __LINE__ . "<br />";` to see how far you get into the script.

Answer (score 1):

You have phpfox setup without licence. So your installation process is not working properly.
Please install it on your local system and upload `server.sett.php` file and database online. And change the credentials in `server.sett.php` file after upload

Comment: I did previousely but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem
This happend when you use phpfox which have not licence. As I know, there is no way. you have to buy a licence.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip Phpfox License Key checking by insert this line : `define('PHPFOX_SKIP_INSTALL_KEY',  true);` into file: install/index.php

Then you can start install Phpfox without license key.

Please notice that you should use it only for experimental purpose only.